# Ionic 2 safely store Google Maps Api Key

Tags: google-maps, cordova, security, ionic2

I have an Ionic application that is using the `cordova google maps plugin`.

In my `config.xml` I have

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.1.1">
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value=“$AFLKSDJFSD" />
    <variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION" value="Show your location on the map" />
    <variable name="LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Trace your location on the map" />
</plugin>
```

I assume, but could be wrong that it is not secure to store the api key in the `config.xml`

Is there a best practice for storing sensitive variables in `config.xml`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [secure storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/) for this purpose.

```
import { SecureStorage, SecureStorageObject } from '@ionic-native/secure-storage';

constructor(private secureStorage: SecureStorage) { }

...
//
this.secureStorage.create('your_storage_name')
  .then((storage: SecureStorageObject) => {
     //get the key from storage
     storage.get('google_api_key')
       .then(
         data => console.log(data),
         error => console.log(error)
     );
     //set the key into storage
     storage.set('key', 'value')
       .then(
        data => console.log(data),
         error => console.log(error)
     );
  });
```

Comment: Can I use this in my `config.xml` file? All examples seem to be in js files

Comment: this have to be in your .ts file.